# Lightning saying I require an attribute 'title' that doesn't exist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to complete the Trailhead module on Aura comps but ran into an error.

```
COMPONENT markup://c:campingList is missing required attribute 'title'
```

There is no 'title' attribute in my CampingList.cmp, however. Why is this error being thrown? Here is the code:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="itemList" type="Camping_Item__c" default = "{'SObjectType':'Camping_Item__c','Quantity__c':'0','Price__c': '0'}"/>

<lightning:card> 
    <lightning:input name="Name" required="true" label="Name" />
    <lightning:input type="number" name="Quantity" required="true" min="1" value="1" label="Quantity - Requires a minimum value of 1" />
    <lightning:input type="number" name="Price" required="true" label="Price"/>
    <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="Packed" required="true" label="Packed"/>

</lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not set attribute `title` in card.

If you check docs of [lightning:card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/specification), `title` attribute is MANDATORY.

```
<lightning:card footer="Card Footer" title="Hello">
    <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button label="New"/>
    </aura:set>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        Card Body (custom component)
    </p>
</lightning:card>
```

Here title is **Hello**

Comment: Duh! Thank you for the quick response. For future reference, is there a clearer way to debug this? I feel like the error message was not very helpful.

Comment: Yes error message is sometimes is not clear. Debugging standard components is very complex. Instead checking documentation would help.